# Docusign soap api method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates to include CC

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I used https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx docusign API. We had predefined templates stored in Docusgin, each templates has about 2 routing order which requires signature in that particular order(Customer as 1, account manager counter sign as #2). We want to add a CC copy(a rep) on each required signature email so sales Rep know the email was truly sent to the customer or account manager.
I don't see a easy way to include the CC as part of signature in the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates api, the only way I research so far is to change the template to add a non signer(CC) at each routing level. Is there any other easy way to accomplish in order to add a CC. It is a easy ask but not a easy implementation.
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method you will have to have that CarbonCopy recipient role defined in the server template. If you do not want to change the template, I would suggest using the more robust method, CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms. That method will allow you to add a CarbonCopy recipient on the fly without changing (hard-coding the role into the) server template. This is just one of the many benefits of this call using [Composite Templates](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20CompositeTemplate%20Usage.htm). Please reference the [CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms.htm).